# Does deleting a Google account also remove his/her installed apps?

Tags: applications, accounts, htc-wildfire-s

I have the HTC Wildfire S. My friend gave it to me and it already has a Google account on it. Now she forget the password. I was just wondering, if I delete the account, will it delete all apps that she already put on the phone? If I don't want to get them deleted, is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

It will not delete the apps but unless you actually want the apps, I would recommend making a different Google account for your own security and your friends' security.Once you remove the email address, you will lose all progress or saved data on those apps though. So as long as you do not care about the saved data with that Google account, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Google account doesn't remove the apps installed over the device until or unless you uninstall them manually.

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't delete all the apps. However, the app accounts which are directly linked with the google account will lose their data as well. So, if you don't worry about the data, go ahead and set it up as a different user.